# UIswitch in UItableview of unknown length

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

How can I implement a `UISwitch` in every cell of a `UITableView`, in order to use the `tableView` as a sort of checklist, which I can then gather the checked items to send to a backend, to 'purchase' the items?

The list of items may change and is located on the app backend, I have already implemented the parsing of the items and the building of the tableview, but I'm just not sure how to assign the switches when the length of the tableview is uncertain.

I'm new to Objective-C and XCode, and couldn't find any answers anywhere, so thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming here that your data is stored in an array.

- In each `UITableViewCell`, where you have added the `UISwitch`, set it's `tag` to same as it's `indexPath.row`.

  ```
  mySwitch.tag = indexPath.row;
  ```
- You can easily get the index of the object for which you had set the switch, using the the `tag` stored.

  ```
  [myArray objectAtIndex:mySwitch.tag];
  ```

Comment: Make sure you reload your table *each* time your data is updated, so that indices for cells correspond to the correct object in your array.